# D3.js calculating group averages

Tags: javascript, d3.js

From objects that contain "name" "tours" and "month" I am trying to figure out how to add up all the "tours" associated with objects that have the same name and then what percentage of the sum total each name's total tours add up to.

there are 5 possible names "marriott", "springhill", etc

I've figured out how to find the total of all tours, but now i need to find out how many tours are associated those 5 names and what percentage of the sum each name's tours takes up.

here's the code and a link to a pen...    `http://codepen.io/mcKrack/pen/Vaggxq?editors=1111`

```js
 var outerWidth = 500;
      var outerHeight = 250;
      var margin = { left: 55, top: 5, right: 100, bottom: 60 };

      var xColumn = "month";
      var yColumn = "tours";
      var colorColumn = "name";
      var areaColumn = colorColumn;

      var xAxisLabelText = "Month";
      var xAxisLabelOffset = 48;

      var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
      var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", outerWidth)
        .attr("height", outerHeight);
      var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var xAxisG = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")")
      var xAxisLabel = xAxisG.append("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (innerWidth / 2) + "," + xAxisLabelOffset + ")")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .text(xAxisLabelText);

      var colorLegendG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "color-legend")
        .attr("transform", "translate(403, 5)");

      var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, innerWidth]);
      var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);
      var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
        .ticks(2)
        .outerTickSize(0);

      var stack = d3.layout.stack()
        .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
        .values(function (d){ return d.values; });

      var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
        .y0(function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
        .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); });

      function render(data){

        var nested = d3.nest()
          .key(function (d){ return d[areaColumn]; })
          .entries(data);

        colorScale.domain(nested.map(function (d){ return d.key; }));

        var layers = stack(nested.reverse());
        console.log(layers);

        xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d[xColumn]; }));
        yScale.domain([
          0,
          d3.max(layers, function (layer){
            return d3.max(layer.values, function (d){
              return d.y0 + d.y;
            });
          })
        ]);

        var total = d3.sum(layers, function(layer) {
         return d3.sum(layer.values, function(d) {
            return d.tours;
          });
        });
        console.log(total);

        var paths = g.selectAll(".chart-area").data(layers);
        paths.enter().append("path").attr("class", "chart-line");
        paths.exit().remove();
        paths
          .attr("d", function (d){ return area(d.values); })
          .attr("fill", function (d){ return colorScale(d.key); });

        xAxisG.call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(layers)
            .enter().append("text")
              .text(function(d) { return (d.key) + ' (' + d.key + ')'; })
              .attr('fill', function(d) { return colorScale(d.key); })
              .attr('y', function(d, i) { return 20 * (i + 1); })
              .attr('x', "0");

      }

      function type(d){
        d.month = new Date(d.month);
        d.tours = +d.tours;
        return d;
      }

var toursByHotel = [
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Residence",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Residence",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Residence",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        }
      ];

      render(toursByHotel);
```

```css
.axis text {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
      }
      .axis .label {
        font-size: 18pt;
      }

      .axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
```

```html
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.1.0/d3-legend.js"></script>
```

Comment: You already have the total (`var total`) and the sum for each hotel (`var totals`). Just divide one by the other.